# yahoo mail ubuntu 19.10 & Geary

Tags: server, email, geary

i've a problem with my yahoo account and geary.

The problem is this: While all my gmail accounts are perfectly configureted, if i choose to use my yahoo account Geary it doesen't work.

Every time i try to set my account, i've the same warning: "account not created: check your email address and password" (i did, and they are correct).

It doesen't work also if i try to configure my account directly from the "Account Online" in the Ubuntu' settings, using the voice "IMAP and SMTP".

The strange things is that i've no problem using it with thunderbird.

Have you any ideas about this problem? i tried to search for bugs, regressions etc. but i've found nothing. Can you help me?

I'd like to use geary for his best integration with Gnome and his great look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use a 3rd party email client, Yahoo Mail wants you to generate a password which is different from the one you use to access your account on https://mail.yahoo.com

You can check [here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/generate-third-party-passwords-sln15241.html) how to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much! it works now!